# auto update code first from database model, is it possible?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6, code-first

I have code first classes which are generated from my existing db using ADO.NET Entity Data Model. Now I've added some new tables to the database.

I want to know if its possible to create associated code classes from the new db tables without (re)creating the model again from scratch?

Comment: This question is a close relative of this one; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637350/how-to-synch-model-after-using-code-first-from-database-using-entity-framework-6 where the answer is, no, this is not possible with a "code first from database" approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is, if you use [Reverse Engineer Code First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx) to do so. It will create POCOs exactly like Code-First, but it will do so based completely on the current database. No .edmx file and no T4 template. Just Code-First.

You should know, by the way, that this (along with regular Code-First) are going to be the only ones allowed in EF7. They are getting rid of many things to try to slim it down, and both Model- and Database-First got the ax (at least, for now). [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/27/ef7-v1-or-v7.aspx) from Microsoft's ADO.NET blog explains that, along with some other features.

Comment: Not sure why this was an accepted answer since the question was clearly asking if the tool could be run again without recreating the model. Based on the information in the link you do have to delete and recreate the existing model class in order to pick up the new schema changes.

Comment: blog post  link is broken